# ReactNative does not install android 33 sdk how to solve it?

Tags: react-native, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

react-native needs about android33 so I installed it, but it still asks me to install it[image]

As above, I installed version 33.
However, if you check the contents with react-native doctor,

```
Android
 ✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: 30.0.3
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
```

I am getting this error, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem but i fixed it like this:

1. Open your android studio SDK Manager
   [SDK-Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPIbT.jpg)
2. Click on SDK Tool Tab
   [SDK-Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwYxM.jpg)
3. Install Android SDK Build-Tools
   [Android SDK Build-Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVQMV.jpg)
4. After install it, click Show Package Details at the bottom like this
   [Expand-Android-SDK-Build-Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL2y5.jpg)
5. Lastly, install necessary version, in your case it would be 33.0.0
   [Version-33.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOPaR.jpg)