# React Native Android studio Setup

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

While Android studio setup we are facing error while executing this below cmt
npx react-native doctor

Error :

✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

- Versions found: N/A
- Version supported: 34.0.0

Already tried not working
[ReactNative does not install android 33 sdk how to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935298/reactnative-does-not-install-android-33-sdk-how-to-solve-it)

Comment: can you please confirm if you have thoroughly followed the installation and setup from the React Native official documentation? and also able to create and launch emulator?